# fullCalendar displayEventTime

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Is there any way to set fullCalendar's displayEventTime for specific events. I have the default set to 'false' but would like to set it 'true' for just some events based on duration of event.
I know I could just add the relevant timings myself to the event title, but just wondered if it could be done within fullCalendar.

Comment: I don't think so, unfortunately. If there was, it would be listed in the properties which can be provided for individual events, at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-parsing. Maybe you should submit a feature request - see https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features